# Яндекс.Контест - Wrong-Answer на последнем тесте

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, test-automation

Всем привет! Мне нужно решить [это задание](https://sun9-35.userapi.com/impg/MzXvZoY397OEFEg1_hAdpsTa78g-B0WA1Hyt-A/oWzaG-0mRUI.jpg?size=797x1887&quality=96&sign=4c7071e755277e2a9ed4d88cc2ee915d&type=album) на Яндекс.Контесте. Написал код, который решает это задание. Однако он все равно не проходит [последний тест](https://sun9-47.userapi.com/impg/bd1Avt_eKH3EeBqxsOm3lRSqtzqWd9iQE3Mnyg/YBzS_TuuxMk.jpg?size=1177x330&quality=96&sign=c561ef592d14da719db9805e644bdebe&type=album). Все [предыдущие тесты](https://sun9-71.userapi.com/impg/ftIYt6lXqpMkNVSs4YBE01raAVgOAcHhHR-BmQ/LwFKvPFNj6Y.jpg?size=1194x927&quality=96&sign=b152146f65cc26d2e586c7149a7eea9c&type=album) программа прошла отлично. В чем причина того, что последний тест программа не проходит?

Код моего решения на Python задачи такой такой:

```py
def setIntWithProverka(e, userInput):
    if 1 <= int(e) and int(e) <= 10**9:
        return int(e)
    else:
        if userInput:
            print(-1)
        else:
            open("output.txt", "w").write(str(-1))
        quit()

userInput = True
try:
    N = int(input())
    V = list(map(lambda e, userInput=userInput: setIntWithProverka(e, userInput), input().split(" ")))
except ValueError:
    userInput = False
    f = open("input.txt")
    content = f.readlines()
    N = int(content[0])
    V = list(map(lambda e, userInput=userInput: setIntWithProverka(e, userInput), content[1].split(" ")))
    f.close()

if not (len(V) == N or not (1 <= N and N <= 100000)):
    if userInput:
        print(-1)
    else:
        open("output.txt", "w").write(str(-1))
    quit()

mx_v = max(V)
k = 0
counter = 0
while len(set(V)) != 1:
    for i in range(len(V)):
        if V[i] != mx_v:
            k += 1

    for k_value in range(k):
        V[k_value] += 1
    counter += 1

    k = 0

    if counter >= 1000:
        if userInput:
            print(-1)
        else:
            open("output.txt", "w").write(str(-1))
        quit()


if userInput:
        print(counter)
else:
    open("output.txt", "w").write(str(counter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идём в цикле по элементам.
Если значение изменилось вниз - аллес капут.
Если значение изменилось вверх на `d`, добавляем к счётчику операций `d`

```
cnt = 0
for i in range(1, len(V)):
    d = V[i] - V[i-1]
    if d < 0:
       cnt = -1
       break
    elif d > 0:
       cnt += d
```

Однако можно заметить, что сумма положительных разностей массива, сортированного по неубыванию - это просто разница последнего и первого элемента, так что можно просто проверить упорядоченность и взять эту самую разницу

```
cnt = V[-1]-V[0]    
for i in range(1, len(V)):
    if V[i] < V[i-1]:
       cnt = -1
       break 
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение работает быстрее, но теперь оно проваливается [на 8 тесте](https://sun9-23.userapi.com/impg/zvlnbUvYIh3SRlT6WnXRVnhvYiTlYdFv8zyGdw/k-YiDXXF7CU.jpg?size=679x420&quality=96&sign=3ce0cedf5ec51c935f78e0bc1c88fa9d&type=album). Мой код выглядит [так](https://pastebin.com/rHApd5t1)

Comment: После  if d < 0:        cnt = -1 надо же break